# Find number of solutions for $x^5 + y^5 \equiv z^5 \;(\bmod\; 25)$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Correct me if I'm wrong, but we can reduce the above to
$x^5 + y^5 \equiv z^5 \;(\bmod\; 5)$ because $5$ is the only prime factor of $25$.
But beyond that, I'm not quite sure how to proceed besides have $x$ or $y$ be equal to zero and have $y$ or $x$ respectively be equal $z$
Would be something like we instead try to find all $z^5$ that divides $x^5 + y^5 -5$?

Comment: The first sentence is not true; the Chinese remainder theorem only works for relatively prime factors.

Answer (score 1):

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}_{25}$.

The mapping $f:R^3\to R^3$ given by $f(x,y,z)=(x,y,-z)$ yields a one-to-one correspondence between the set 
$$
S=\{(x,y,z)\in R^3{\,\mid\,}x^5+y^5=z^5\}
$$
and the set
$$
\;\;\;\;\;\,T=\{(x,y,z)\in R^3{\,\mid\,}x^5+y^5+z^5=0\}
$$
so $|S|=|T|$.

Thus it suffices to find $|T|$.

Let $(x,y,z)\in T$, with $x,y,z\in\{0,...,24\}$

By the division algorithm we can write
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{align*}
x&=5a+x_1\\[4pt]
y&=5b+y_1\\[4pt]
z&=5c+z_1\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
\right.
$$
where $0\le a,b,c\le 4$ and $0\le x_1,y_1,z_1\le 4$.

Expanding $x,y,z$ via the binomial theorem, it follows that in $R$ we have
$$
x^5=x_1^5,\;\;\;y^5=y_1^5,\;\;\;z^5=z_1^5
$$
so $x^5+y^5+z^5=0$ if and only if $x_1^5+y_1^5+z_1^5=0$.

Hence since there are $5$ choices for each of $a,b,c$, it follows that $|T|=5^3{\,\cdot\,}|T_1|$, where
$$
T_1=\{(x_1,y_1,z_1){\,\mid\,}x_1^5+y_1^5+z_1^5=0\}
$$
Let $(x_1,y_1,z_1)\in T_1$.

In $R$ we have
$$
0^5,1^5,2^5,3^5,4^5=0^5,1^5,2^5,(-2)^5,(-1)^5=0,1,7,-7,-1
$$
hence by inspection, since $x_1^5+y_1^5+z_1^5=0$, the triple $(x_1^5,y_1^5,z_1^5)$ must be some permutation of one of the triples
$$
(1,-1,0),\;\;\;(7,-7,0),\;\;\;(0,0,0)
$$
Of those $3$ triples, there are $6$ ways to permute each of the first two, and only one way to permute the third, hence there are $6{\,\cdot\,}2+1=13$ possibilities for the triple
$(x_1^5,y_1^5,z_1^5)$.

Since the map from $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ to $R$ given by $r\mapsto r^5$ is injective, it follows that there are $13$ possibilities for the triple $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$.

Thus $|T_1|=13$, so $|T|=5^3{\,\cdot\,}13=1625$.